# Why are my CLLocationManagerDelegate methods not called?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Calling class...

```
     @implementation MenuViewController

     - (void)viewDidLoad {
         [super viewDidLoad];

         FuelSiteLocator *siteLocator = [[FuelSiteLocator alloc]init];
         [siteLocator getStations:@"Unleaded Regular"];

         ...
     }
```

And this is the class that isn't working...

```
    @implementation FuelSiteLocator {
        CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    }

    -(id) initWithSearchType {
        locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
        [locationManager setDelegate:self];
        return self;
    }

    -(void) getStations:(NSString *)search {
        [self setSearchType:search];
        [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    }

    -(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
    }

    -(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
        [self getGasStations:[locations lastObject]];
    }

    -(void) getGasStations:(CLLocation *) currentLocation {
        NSLog(@"Hello Gas Stations..");
    }
```

The delegate methods are not being called and I have no idea why... In FuelSiteLocator.h I'm using the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol

******Problem Solved*********
ARC is releasing the siteLoactor object after getStations is called. The delegate methods never had a chance

Comment: Is that your init method? Why aren't you calling `super`?

Comment: Your init method doesn't call `super`?

Comment: Im calling super in the view did load.. the FuelSiteLocator is a model class that I'm instantiating an object of

Comment: That's got nothing to do with the `FuleSiteLocator` object.

Comment: Not to demotivate you or anything, but you need to learn basic OOP concepts like inheritance before you get too deep into this stuff.

Comment: Sorry, but that attitude won't help you get solutions to your problems here.

Comment: I think what's happening is ARC is releasing the siteLocator object after the call to getStations

Comment: Yup.. keep up the criticisms duic9y. real constructive

Comment: Criticism? Perhaps you meant 'suggestion'? Reiterating it, don't forget to call `[super init…]`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier in the comments, your `init` method is not correct.

try:

```
-(id) initWithSearchType:(NSString *)search {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.searchType = search;
        self.locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}
```

(This assumes the class inherits from `NSObject`, as I haven't seen the class definition).